# How to set retention days to a logstream with cloudformation or yaml

Tags: python, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

So, I have been working back and forth with this task.

I have AWS CloudWatch logs where I have to apply retention policies to some logstreams of a Loggroup

Loggroup: "My Loggroup"
and inside it I have different logstreams
Logstream-a
Logstream-b

what I want to do, is to set different retention days to each logstream.

Logstream-a = 180 days
Logstream-b = 90 days

I've found that I can set the retention settings to a loggroup in YAML, but I can't do that to a logstream.

```
CloudWatchLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: MyLoggroup
      RetentionInDays: 180
```

Is there any way to apply retention settings to a LogStream with Python, Cloudformation or YAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already discovered, you can [set log retention](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html#SettingLogRetention) on `LogGroups`, but not on `LogStreams`.

You could use [CloudWatch S3 exports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html) to differentiate retention by `LogStream` indirectly.  What makes S3 exports work for your use case is that [export tasks](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.create_export_task) can filter exports by `logStreamNamePrefix`.

```py
# CloudWatchLogs.Client
response = client.create_export_task(
    taskName='string',
    logGroupName='string',
    logStreamNamePrefix='string', # Export only log streams that match the provided prefix
    fromTime=123,
    to=123,
    destination='string',
    destinationPrefix='string'
)
```

- Set the `LogGroup` retention days to the shortest retention category.  All logs in CW expire at that time.
- Create export tasks for the `LogSteams` that belong to the longer retention categories.
- Create [expiry lifecycle rules in S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to automatically delete objects after a set number of days.  Rules can filter by object prefix, which handily corresponds to the log stream names.
- Run the export tasks periodically.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this, I will start to work on this solution right away :)